# For orthogonal matrices $A$ and $B$, prove $\det(A^{t}B - B^{t}A)=\det(A+B)\det(A-B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, orthogonal-matrices

I can't prove this formula:
$$
\det(A^{t}B - B^{t}A)=\det(A+B)\det(A-B)
$$

I tried using fact that $A^{t}A = I$ (similarly for $B$):
$$
A^{t}B-B^{t}A=A^{t}B-B^{t}A + A^{t}A - B^{t}B=A^{t}(A+B)+B^{t}(A - B)
$$

I don't understand how I should continue, and don't see an alternative method.

Comment: I think you just made a sign error.  It should be $-B^t(A+B)$ not $B^t(A-B)$

Comment: yes I see, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It results that

\begin{align}
A^{t}B-B^{t}A&=A^{t}B-B^{t}A+I-I=\\&=\color{blue}{A^{t}B}\color{red}{-B^{t}A}+\color{blue}{A^{t}A}\color{red}{-B^{t}B}=\\&=\color{blue}{A^{t}(A+B)}\color{red}{-B^{t}(A+B)}=\\&=(A+B)(A^t-B^t)=(A+B)(A-B)^t\,.
\end{align}

Since $\;\det(A-B)^t=\det(A-B)\;,\;$ we get that

$$\det(A^{t}B-B^{t}A)=\det(A+B)\det(A-B)\,.$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks